# Why is awk's OFS only applied to the first line?

Tags: awk, cygwin

I'm doing some simple calculations on a file using awk, but cannot get the output formatting right. The OFS is for some reason only applied to the first line (i.e. only within the BEGIN block), and for other rows a single space is inserted between fields.

Input:

```
title   c1  c2  c3  n
AA  14  6   3   40
BB  8   2   2   38
```

Oneliner:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Title","Freq1","Freq2","Freq3","Total"}; NR>1{printf "%s %.3f %.3f %.3f %d\n", $1, $2/$5, $3/$5, $4/$5, $5;}' > file2.txt
```

I've tried removing the header from BEGIN but this does not make a difference, and neither does `BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t";...}`. I'm using awk in cygwin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using `printf` you are actively avoiding OFS entirely. If you want to incorporate OFS, it gets ugly:

```
NR>1 {printf "%s%s%.3f%s%.3f%s%.3f%s%d\n", $1, OFS, $2/$5, OFS, $3/$5, OFS, $4/$5, OFS, $5}
```

Or, don't use printf:

```
NR>1 {print $1, sprintf("%.3f",$2/$5), sprintf("%.3f",$3/$5), sprintf("%.3f",$4/$5), $5}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Really annoying restriction with printf, since you are still defining fields with commas, with the default separator still applied.

Comment: Like the sprintf solution better - didn't know about sprintf before.

Comment: re first comment, no you're not. You're explicitly specifying the output format, and the commas are to separate arguments to the printf command so it can fill in the placeholders correctly.

Comment: I see. I thought that the field separators were coming from my commas and not the spaces in the specification of printf formatting. However, I then tried to insert the tabs in the printf formatting as well as `{printf "%s\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%d\n", $1, $2/$5, $3/$5, $4/$5, $5;}` and this also works.